# coding for a file override

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, ibm-midrange

I am looking to create a file override from within VBA.
I have an AS/400 file linked to the data base but I need to override that file in order to use the AS/400 file's member. Each user running the report in Access will have his/her own member on the AS/400. I need to do this so that multiple users can run the report at the same time. Not feasible to link all of the user's files.
I have found some statements that should work but I am not sure I have correctly populated the parm.
This what I have:

```
rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, hdbc)
If rc = SQL_SUCCESS Then
   stmt = "call qsys.qcmdexc(‘OVRDBF FILE(qspexrpt) TOFILE(bnldta/qspexrpt) MBR(" + userid + ") OVRSCOPE(*JOB)’, 0000000071.00000)”)"
   rc1 = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, stmt, SQL_NTS)  
End If
```

What I expect to happen: The linked file will be overridden with file member from the OVRDBF command.
The problem is that I am not successfully returning a 0 in the rc field in the SQLAllocHandle statement.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! can you put more information about what you were expecting to happen, and what's actually wrong?

Comment: Is the problem with SQLAllocHandle or with SQLExecDirect?  Is 71 bytes long enough to hold the entire OVRDBF command (including a possible 10 bytes of user name)?

Answer (score 2):

A better option would be to use the [CREATE ALIAS](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzhcalias.htm) statement to create a temporary alias pointing to the library/file/member in QTEMP and perform your database operations over that:

```
CREATE ALIAS QTEMP.userid FOR BNLDTA.QSPEXPRT(userid)
```

---

```
rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, hdbc)
If rc = SQL_SUCCESS Then
    stmt = "CREATE ALIAS QTEMP." + userid + " FOR BNLDTA.QSPEXRPT(" + userid + ")"
    rc = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, stmt, SQL_NTS)  
    If rc = SQL_SUCCESS Then
        stmt = "SELECT * FROM QTEMP." + userid
        rc = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, stmt, SQL_NTS)  
        If rc = SQL_SUCCESS Then
            . . .
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: can you provide a vba example to do this?

Comment: @dino624 Updated with an example.

Comment: JamesA, Can you tell me what values are needed in hstmt and hdbc

Comment: I am receiving a -2 in the rc field after the statement: rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, hdbc)

Comment: @dino624 See [SQLAllocHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for all the gritty details.

Comment: @dino624 This will be a lot easier if you use ADO to execute the SQL and dynamically create your linked table(s) at startup.

Comment: I did review the SQLAllocHandle info but it does not tell what to populate those fields with. as far as using ADO, can you provide an example of this and how I would link the table to the report. I currently have qspexrpt set up as a linked table to the report that is why I thought doing the alias might work or the ovrdbf which I tried earlier. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Note that an ALIAS might not be appropriate in cases where each user has a member. In some cases, users have members in more than one table, and that quickly causes management problems. (Just managing singles might be a problem in some cases.) Also, creating an ALIAS creates a permanent object with bits of overhead including object creation (and perhaps deletion if not in QTEMP), ownership, authority checking, etc. A simple properly scoped override is possibly the best solution in most cases.